# Why is my FileReader/BufferReader returning both the sentence and null?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

The main thing I am trying to do is input a .txt file into a 2d char array. The problem is that no data is being saved into the array, so I'm thinking my problem lies with the fact that there is no in-between string from the .txt file to the array. I tried using file and buffered readers so I would have a string, and it works, but it adds null many many times. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? (I am very new to java, sorry for any errors in question format and such)

See code below, where I'm encountering the problem.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Code.txt"));
        
    try {   
        //had a problem trying to just get the chars out from a file just as a string
        // so to a filereader we go!
            FileReader Enigma = new FileReader("Code.txt");
            // when looking at filereaders, i found bufferedreaders
            // they seem to help with reading chars better than the filereader alone
            BufferedReader CryptoMachine = new BufferedReader(Enigma);
            
            for (i = 0; i <= rows-1; i++)
            {
                
                for (j = 0; j <= columns-1; j++)
                {
                    sentence = CryptoMachine.readLine();
                    System.out.print(sentence);
                }
            }
            CryptoMachine.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No file found");
        }
```

Return I get:

```
This is ridiculously hardnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

Whole code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    // TODO block code
    public class Enigma {
    // TODO block code
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        
        // double array set up here
        String sentence = "";
        int rows = 6;
        int columns = 7;
        char[][] RotaryMachine = new char[rows][columns];
        boolean flag = false;
        
        // told this lets me declare variables on the same line
        int i = 0,j = 0;
        // scanner to scan a file here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Code.txt"));
        
    try {   
        //had a problem trying to just get the chars out from a file just as a string
        // so to a filereader we go!
            FileReader Enigma = new FileReader("Code.txt");
            // when looking at filereaders, i found bufferedreaders
            // they seem to help with reading chars better than the filereader alone
            BufferedReader CryptoMachine = new BufferedReader(Enigma);
            
            for (i = 0; i <= rows-1; i++)
            {
                
                for (j = 0; j <= columns-1; j++)
                {
                    sentence = CryptoMachine.readLine();
                    System.out.print(sentence);
                }
            }
            CryptoMachine.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No file found");
        }
            
            for(i = 0; j > columns && !flag;++i)
            {
                if(i < rows && !scanner.hasNext())
                {
                    System.out.println("The English have our codes");
                    flag = true;
                }
                RotaryMachine[i][j] = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                if(i > 6)
                {
                    j++;
                }
                RotaryMachine[i][j] = '*';
            }
    

    //  RotaryMachine[0][0] = 'a';
            
            //now, to hopefully code the scrambler section properly, for Enigma to work!
            // V2 seems to keep letters really close together
            for(i=0;i < columns;++i)
            {
            for(j = 0;j < rows;++j)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%c", RotaryMachine[j][i]);
                }
            }   
                
                
            // V1 of the code   seems to space out the letters
        //      for(j=0;j < rows;++j)
            //  {
        //          for(i = 0;i < columns;++i)
            //      {
        //              System.out.printf("%c", RotaryMachine[j][i]);
            //      }
        //      }
                
            
            }
    }
```

Comment: it is the indication of end of file. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) of `readLine`: *"**Returns:**...or null if the end of the stream has been reached..."*

Comment: Are you sure there are 6*7 lines in the file?

Comment: There is only one line, I want to take a sentence and seperate them into characters, including spaces, and input them into the array

Comment: I'm just not sure how to properly do that

Comment: one line, then do not repeat `readLine`, just call it once

Comment: If there is only 1 line then why do you call `readLine()` 42 times? There's your problem. Call it once and spit the string into characters.

Comment: to get the `char`s from a String use `sentence.toCharArray()` (or `sentence.charAt(index)` for a single one) - to split into Strings `sentence.split("")` (mostly not recommended, unless you really need one char Strings)

Comment: ok this is awesome, I appreciate the help

Comment: how can I mark this question as answered? I'm a bit new to Stack Overflow

Comment: you can also read just one `char` from file `(char) CryptoMachine.read()`, but then you must manage end of line or end of file and such

Comment: @Aether Since there are no answers, only comments, an answer cannot be marked as the solution. You can create an answer of your own if you so wish and then mark that as the solution or allow others to consolidate these comments into an answer and mark that.

Comment: Aha, okay, might do just that once I'm done programming, thanks for the input

Comment: I'm feeling a bit bored today, went ahead and made an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the file being read only has one line, `readLine` will return `null` for every call past the first since there are no more lines to read.

You can `String.split` the initial string after reading it if you so desire.